# Center nav bar foundation5 framework?

Tags: html, css

I've searched a lot and tried multiple changes but I can't get my nav bar to center.

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
  <ul class="title-area">
      <li class="name">
                </li>
                  </ul>
                    <section class="top-bar-section">
                         <ul class="center">
                         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Client Area</a></li>
                         </ul>
                        </section>
</nav>
```

CSS is quite large so I used Pastebin - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=E8WQT41K

No matter what I try it remains at the left.

Comment: first remove data-topbar or make it data-topbar="". Second. all you have to do is add .top-bar{position: relative; display: block; margin: 0 auto; width 500px;}... I did not look at you css as it was too much to read.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.your css is too long.apply this css for your nav part only

```
.title-area
{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
}
.top-bar-section
{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.center
{
  list-style:none;  
}
.center li
{
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XNCj7/2/

Comment: I tried it, removed everything but that however there is no change.

Comment: see the jsfiddle link.is this u want right if stil its not working means provide ur url